# Partial auto incrementing

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a note-taking application. I want to retrieve notes by retrieving the note id (1 or 2 or 3 etc.) from the user_id. 
For example, I want to retrieve note 3 from user 1 and also retrieve note 3 from user 2, but I want the note numbers to auto-increment for each user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app does not have to deal with a lot of concurrency (*only one instance of the same user is online at any given time*), then this simple solution will work just fine:

```
SELECT max(note_id) + 1 AS new_id
FROM   notes
WHERE  user_id = $user_id;
```

Be sure to have an index on `user_id` in the table `notes` or even on `(user_id, note_id)` to make the look-up fast.

Comment: LOCK the tabel before this query, MAX() will be the same for everybody! This doesn't work when there is any form of concurrency possible and/or happening. When all is done, UNLOCK the table.

Comment: @FrankHeikens: `max(note_id)` will be the same for the same `user_id` - not for everybody. Only if two queries for the same user can happen concurrently, it will be a problem.